# search form: submit refresh only partial after every keypressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, form-submit

I'm trying to do a search form that refresh a partial after every input: when I do only :

```
$("#search-field-id").on('input', function() {
    console.log("keypressed");
    $("#search-form").submit();
 });
```

it refresh all the page, so I'm trying to change the submit default functionality but it's not working:

```
$("#search-field-id").on('input', function() {
    console.log("keypressed");
    $("#search-form").submit(function(e){
      console.log("submitting");
      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "#{translations_path}",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          $.get({
            url: "#{translations_path}",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
              partial: 'translation_key_list'
            },
            success: function(data){
              $("#translations-list").html(data)
            }
          });
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

what am I doing wrong?

the view:

```
.search-form
  = form_tag(translations_path, method: :get, id:"search-form", remote:true) do
    .ui.icon.input
      = text_field_tag :key_we_looking_for, params[:key_we_looking_for], id:"search-field-id"
      = submit_tag 'Search', name:nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$("#search-field-id").on('input', function() {
    console.log("keypressed");
     performGet();
  });




 function performGet(){
    console.log("submitting");
              $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "#{translations_path}",
                data:$("#search-form").serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                  $.get({
                    url: "#{translations_path}",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: {
                      partial: 'translation_key_list'
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                      $("#translations-list").html(data)
                    }
                  });
                }
              });

}
```

Let us know if this works.

**PS** I have written e.preventDefault() before the ajax post.

Following your Comment
I suggest not to use the form submit itself.

I have updated the code.

Comment: No, I don't have to to do the 4 first line you wrote, because doing only {$("#search-form").submit();} refresh the whole page, and writing e.preventDefault() before the ajax post didn't change anything

Comment: Now both log are appearing on every touch, but it still doesn't work, i think it's because my ajax query is not correct

Comment: Can you please let us know what exactly is the problem, so that we can think of a better solution. But for the question i feel this does answers.

Comment: The problem is that it still not refreshing the partial, so I'm guessing the submit isn't working

Comment: Well you need to check you inner ajax call then

Comment: In data:$("#search-form").serialize(), I have the answer but the whole page, is there any way I can take only a partial data from that ?,so i can put it on the partial needed?

Comment: two options: 1) use serializeArray(); insetad of searilize() , 2) take the form values manually and make a json object, stringify it and send to the controller

Comment: I maybe miss explained, I want to get only some informations from the response that, the first get ajax, give me, since it give all the page with the information that I need in it. and I don't see how can I use serializeArray() in that case